# Scrapy: crawlspider not generating all links and Data in Given links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I cant able to scrap the Data in the below URL. I tried to Scrap that, but in my machine it shows some unrelated data.

URL 1:  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=samsung%20appliances&sprefix=samsung+applia%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Asamsung%20appliances

URL 2:  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Asamsung+appliances&page=2&keywords=samsung+appliances&ie=UTF8&qid=1391033912

Coding:

Line 1:   hxs.select('//h3[@class="newaps"]/span/text()').extract()

Line 2:   hxs.select('//h3[@class="newaps"]/a/@href').extract()
Expected Output :

For URL 1 & Line 1

Samsung RF4289HARS
Samsung Heating Element DC47-00019A 
Samsung WIS12ABGNX Wireless LAN Adapter
Samsung SMH1816S 1.8 Cu. Ft. Stainless Steel Over-the-Range Microwave
Samsung RF4287 28 Cubic Foot French Door Refrigerator with 4 Doors and Integrated Water & Ice, Real Stainless
.
.
.
etc.....

And i need for Line 2 code in the above, then i need for URL 2 also ..

See my code .........

```
    From scrapy.spider import BaseSpider      
    from scrapy.http import Request    
    from urlparse import urljoin        
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector    
    import inspect    
    from amazon.items import AmazonItem    

    class amzspider(BaseSpider):
        name="amz"    

        start_urls=["http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Asamsung+appliances&page=2&keywords=samsung+appliances&ie=UTF8&qid=1386153209"]
        print start_urls           

    def parse(self,response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)


        ul=hxs.select('//div/ul[@class="rsltGridList grey"]').extract()
        l=len(hxs.select('//h3[@class="newaps"]/a/@href').extract())

        x=[]

        x1=[]
        url1=[]
        for i in range(l):
            x1.append(hxs.select('//h3[@class="newaps"]/a/@href').extract()[i].encode('utf-8').strip())


        print "URl parsed"          

        for i in range(l):
            url1.append(urljoin(response.url, x1[i]))

        for i in range(l):
            if url1[i]:
                yield Request(url1[i], callback=self.parse_sub)     

        r=hxs.select('//a[@id="pagnNextLink"]/@href').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')

        if r:
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, r), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_sub(self,response):
        print " sub callled"
        itm=[]
#       item = response.meta.get('item')
        item=AmazonItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

Comment: I am used Scrapy shell to check that data

Comment: I updated my question, is that clear for you to Understand. if yes, please check that code

Comment: I am using HTML xpath selector I didn't use the Rules.

Comment: Actually I need to get the every Product URL ( I mean Sub URL ) in the URL 1 & 2.  for that i used the below code ,but i show some unrelated data in my screen.                                         <   hxs.select('//h3[@class="newaps"]/a/@href').extract()[i].encode('utf-8').strip()     >